# Rails: Basic Authentication with Authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, authlogic

I'm using Authlogic and I would like to implement Basic HTTP Authentication in my controller so I could define which action requires authentication.

I know how to do Basic HTTP Authentication authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic an before_filter, but I would like to here from other how to implement it with Authlogic plugin.

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController  
  before_filter :authenticate , :only => [:index, :create]
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here is a great screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/160-authlogic) that explains, step-by-step, how to use authlogic in your rails project.

Once authlogic is set up, define the following useful authentication-related helper methods in your Application Controller.

```
def current_user_session
  return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
  @current_user_session = UserSession.find
end

def current_user
  return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
  @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.record
end

def require_user
  unless current_user
    store_location
    flash[:notice] = "You must be logged in to access this page"
    redirect_to new_user_session_url
    return false
  end
end

def require_no_user
  if current_user
    store_location
    flash[:notice] = "You must be logged out to access this page"
    redirect_to root_url
    return false
  end
end
```

Once those methods are defined, you can specify actions that require the user to be logged in:

```
before_filter :require_user, :only => [:new, :edit]
```

Comment: I did this but this is not for REST protocol. I'm trying to create a Basic HTTP Authentication where a client must send authentication header.

Comment: This code doesn't actually use HTTP Basic, but the below solution does.

Answer (score 28):

I've had success with the following:

Define a filter method in application_controller.rb

```
def require_http_auth_user
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
    if user = User.find_by_login(username) 
      user.valid_password?(password)
    else
      false
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your controller you can do the following:

```
  before_filter : require_http_auth_user
```

You can then use:

http://username:password@yoursite.com (i.e. http basic authentication)

Hope this helps.