# HTTP Basic Authentication with Authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic, basic-authentication

I'm trying to get http basic authentication working on my rails app. I am running the app with nginx and passenger. I have the authlogic gem working and my authentication works. I have even used the single_access_token successfully. For some reason though, I am not able to authenticate using http basic authentication. As I understand, I shouldn't need to set anything up for it to work as it is enabled by default. I don't even know where to look through logs to figure this out.

I did some further testing and found out that i can authenticate with basic http authentication using curl on my mac but on my linux box wget does not work, using the same username/password. I have also tried with firefox from my linux box with no success.

Answer (score 0):

This ground has been covered on SO [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285474/rails-basic-authentication-with-authlogic/2327135#2327135).