# Implementing API for a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rest

I am building an API for my rails app i am trying to reuse same controllers for both API and app logic. The requests without authenticating a user is fine but how to implement if some actions need an authentication. I am using authlogic, to edit people need some specific permissions which i am checking in the before_filter. If i implement an API using http basic authentication how do i differentiate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two parts to the answer. Firstly you need to set up http basic auth with authlogic. The details for doing that are contained in this SO answer: [Rails: Basic Authentication with Authlogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285474/rails-basic-authentication-with-authlogic/2327135#2327135)

Then you need to differentiate between API calls and normal browser calls in your controller. Assuming your API is XML or JSON, you can do that with something like this:

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
   before_filter :authorize

   def authorize
      if params[:format] == 'json' || params[:format] == 'xml' 
         require_http_auth_user # http basic auth for API access
      else
         require_user # normal authlogic authentication 
      end
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be worthwhile separating into two separate controllers and including the common functionality via a mixin. That way you can auth the controllers separately.