# Using authlogic with iPhone client using ASIHTTPRequest or NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, ios, asihttprequest, authlogic

I am currently working on an iPhone front end for a rails service that uses vanilla authlogic for authentication. I am completely stuck on how to login to authlogic from the iPhone using ASIHTTPRequest or possibly NSURLConnection. How do I get the current user once I am already logged in? I have found many similar questions here on Stack Overflow but none of them provided good, in depth answers. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out! Authlogic supports http basic authentication, there is an explanation of this here [Rails: Basic Authentication with Authlogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285474/rails-basic-authentication-with-authlogic) This is what ASIHTTPRequest uses.

Hope this helps anyone else who is as lost as I was.